# OSX Automator - How to AppleScript Consecutive Pages

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm new to automator and I'm trying to create a flow that will:

1. Open a web page
2. AppleScript 1 -- Fill out inputs, click submit
3. Safari navigates to the next page
4. AppleScript 2 -- Fill out more inputs, click submit

I'm able to get steps 1, 2, and 3 working fine. After hitting the first submit, Safari opens the next page. However, my script for the next page isn't running correctly. I believe it's running both AppleScripts on the first page. Is there a way to make sure the second script is running on the second page?

My flow actions look like this:

1. Get Specified URLs
2. Display Web Pages
3. Run AppleScript
4. Get Current Web Page from Safari
5. Run AppleScript

Comment: Was able to sort of work around this using delays, it's not perfect but it works. Ideally there would be a way to restrict scripts to a given page

Comment: My solution would look like this: `AppleScript`.  See what I did there ?